# `:r!` in vscode with vim emulation

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, visual-studio-code, git-bash

One of the features I love in vim is `[Esc]:r! <unix command>` to insert the output of a unix command in the file I am editing.  I use that for example to include calendars (`:r! cal`), a timestamp (`:r! date`), the value of a system variable (`:r! echo $PATH`), etc

I was able to replicate *some* of this functionality in VScode thanks to the Vim emulation provided by vscodevim (kudos to those guys: y'all are awesome!).  Unfortunately, in my Windows 10 all I can run are CMD commands.  For instance, for a timestamp I need to call e.g. (`:r! time /t`)---if I forget the `/t` bit, then VScode freezes.  I tried powershell and git-bash commands, but no luck.  Does anyone know how to avoid CMD in favor of any of these other two?

Comment: Does that just use VS Code's integrated terminal feature? If so, try configuring that: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows

Comment: Thanks, muru.  That's we we tried first (we chose PowerShell), but it didn't change the behaviour of `:r!`.  Now when we invoke Ctrl-` we do get PowerShell, though.

Comment: Have you tried playing with `:set shell=` in the Vim emulation? I have not had luck yet with `:set shell=c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe` or my `git-bash.exe` path either (they exit with 126 when I run `r! <anything>`), but there might be a way to wrestle with this and make it work. In any case, I see that `shell=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` when my gvim for Windows starts, and this setting is what tells Vim what shell to use with `:r!` and `:!`.

Comment: Great idea, joanis!  Although it doesn't work yet (I get a warning in VScode saying "Vim Error: Unsupported option. shell"), this could lead to figuring out how vscodevim works.  Thanks!